# What's the attitude towards questions where I'm simply curious about the answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I've asked a bunch of questions <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314675/is-there-an-event-for-when-the-title-attribute-shows-the-tooltip)</sup> <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565733/add-a-string-of-html-attributes-to-a-html-element)</sup> that I don't actually need the answers to, but I posted them because I was just curious what the solution would be.

For example:

> IDK about the solution to problem X.
>
> Pls help.
>
> BTW I don't need the answer, just curious.

Are these sort of questions (written in more respectful language of course) generally welcomed on Stack Overflow, or are they not, because they aren't actually a problem for me? Do I need to mention that it's not even a problem for me, and that I'm just curious?

---

A couple of things to note:

1. The questions I'm talking about aren't code golf, because these are actually practical questions, and I didn't know the answers to them myself.
2. They were just hypothetical programming problems that I'd thought up, that other people *may* actually run into in the future and find useful.
3. I'm not posting this to complain about downvotes, etc. (they were both well received), but because I'm curious (again :)

Comment: It depends entirely on the subject matter. Sometimes, if worded well, these types of questions can be on topic, or even popular/wildly useful. but they can also be off topic or not useful.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164436/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-objective-questions-asked-out-of-curiosity

Comment: Keep in mind the help center requires *"...specific programming problem..."* AND *"...practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development..."*. You may run afoul by asking about hypothetical problems that *don't* exist. For example, how much interest is there in hypothetical solutions to C++ compiler errors when asked to compile a Node.js source file. If someone were to ask it, my observation might be it belongs in a chat room.

Comment: Well, checking them, you *did* provide your attempt to answer. As long as the question and correct answer would be *of use to future programmers* then I think that's fine. If they're just useless outside of curiosity, it's a little abusive of the community to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why you're asking the question is irrelevant to the question and its quality. The question is no better or worse if you're asking because your boss told you to solve that problem than if you just wanted to know for your own sake. In either situation the question could be good or bad.

Note that there's no reason for you to say in the question that you don't need to know the answer. That's just noise and should be edited out if you see irrelevant information like that in a question.

It is however worth noting that SO is a site for *practical* programming problems, so while your personal motivations for asking the question are irrelevant, the question still needs to be of practical value to programmers, as well as being clear, appropriately scoped, and all of the other things every question needs to be. While it's certainly *possible* to ask a good question when you don't actually need to know, there's a tendency for people to not necessarily have a *practical* question, and for it to be appropriately scoped, when asking questions like these, so you should make sure to be somewhat cautious in situations like these.